# Catching code that re-sets a property that is already a default

Tags: javascript, constructor, properties, eslint

I'm working on a legacy project, and someone had a pattern of duplicating what was already set by a constructor, i.e:

```js
export class User()
{
    constructor()
    {
        this.name = "Default";
    }
}

const user = new User();
user.name = "Default";
```

Is it possible to catch these with lint or an IDE like webstorm? I'd like to clean things up.

Looked in lint, webstorm, searched around. I understand that there might be a time to do this on purpose, but I'd like to be able to review. There's a lot of these.